# Google cloud build - Deploy a Cloud function passing clear ENV vars but also KMS secretEnv vars in the same step

Tags: encryption, environment-variables, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

In a cloudbuild template, I have a step to deploy a Cloud function.
I try to deploy the function passing clear environment variables but also secretEnv at the same step.

I have tried several things without success and the documentation is clear about the fact we cannot use --set-env-vars and --env-vars-file nor --update-env-vars in the same command.

**Does anyone succeeded in sending both variables types: clear ones from a file and secret ones with secretEnv ?**

The following definition successfully create variables from .env.prod.yaml  but USER and PASSWORD secrets are not created into the Cloud function.

```
  steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['functions',
       'deploy', 'my-function',
       '--runtime', 'go111',
       '--entry-point', 'MyFunction',
       '--env-vars-file', '.env.prod.yaml',
       '--trigger-topic', 'my-topic']
    secretEnv: ['USER', 'PASSWORD']
  secrets:
  - kmsKeyName: projects/my-project/locations/global/keyRings/my-keyring/cryptoKeys/my-key
      secretEnv:
        USER: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Any ideas, best practice or nice workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deploy the function twice. First to deploy the changes and set the env variables from the file, and then again using the `--update-env-vars` to add encrypted variables.

As per the [Updating environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#updating_environment_variables) documentation, the `--update-env-vars` will not remove all existing environment variables before adding new ones.

An example of the `cloudbuild.yaml` could be:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy',  'my-function’,
     '--runtime', 'go111',
     '--entry-point', 'MyFunction',
     '--env-vars-file', 'env.prod.yaml',
     '--trigger-topic', 'my-topic']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud functions deploy my-function --update-env-vars USER=$$USER,PASSWORD=$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USER', 'PASSWORD']
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/[PROJECT-ID]/locations/global/keyRings/[KEYRING-NAME]/cryptoKeys/[KEY-NAME]
  secretEnv:
    USER: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks, pragmatical

Answer (score 1):

Plaintext environment variables should be set on the build step itself in the `env` field:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  env:
  - USER=my-username
  secretEnv: ['PASSWORD']

secretEnv:
- kmsKeyName: projects/...
  secretEnv:
    PASSWORD: ajklddafjkalda....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it . Nevertheless I found the feature of external file with  "--env-vars-file" very useful. There are cases when we have to generate the environment file dynamically with many variables and then rely on it for the build steps. Whereas changing the variables into the compilation file is less practical.